# How to use javassist to replace a class on runtime

Tags: java, javassist

don't know anyone use javassist here, I want a sample code. I have a user-input java source string, I can compile it and my question is how to use javassist to replace this new class with the old one in memory, anyone can show the sample code?
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you check official tutorial for javassist? http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: @popfalushi seems hotswapper of http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/index.html may works for me, have a try.